# MVC .net Data Annotations Not Rendering for list items in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, data-annotations

I have a list in a model and using Data Annotations for validating the model properties.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string FirstName
{
   get
   {
       return _firstname;
   }
   set
   {
       _firstname = value;
   }
}
```

In the view I have a loop to display each item in the list.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyPersonsList)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
}
```

However, when I look at the rendered HTML source, only the first item in the list renders the "proper" validation attributes.  The second to the last items are missing the validation attributes:  **data-val-required="Required" data-val="true".**

```
<input type="text" value="Roy." name="item.FirstName" id="item_FirstName" data-val-required="Required" data-val="true">
<input type="text" value="Elaine" name="item.FirstName" id="item_FirstName">
<input type="text" value="Jack" name="item.FirstName" id="item_FirstName">
```

So my question is how can I get all items in the list to be rendered correctly with the data annotations (like the first item in the list)?  Or is there a better way of validating the list in the model?